# 400 Bad Request not finding defined 404 error page

Tags: .htaccess

If I mistype a URL for one of my sites and intentionally pull up the 400 Bad Request, I'm getting this message:

> Bad Request
>
> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
>   Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

which is standard and expected, except I have a 404 page setup and defined using .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 400 http://www.mywebsite.com/error
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.mywebsite.com/error
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.mywebsite.com/error
```

Why isn't the browser recognizing this on a 400 error?

My 404 page is working when typing in a non-existent URL.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> ErrorDocument 404 http://www.mywebsite.com/error
> ```

You shouldn't define your `ErrorDocument` directives with an absolute URL. In doing so it will trigger an external 3xx redirect to the error document, not an internal subrequest (recommended). By triggering an external redirect you lose all the server variables associated with the document that triggered the error (status code, requested URL, etc.).

However, this may or may not be related to your current query.

Do you have exceptions in your `.htaccess` file to allow unconditional access to your error documents?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the error page in the root directory. 
If you are looking this in php/html and you have condition to not to show filename extension in the url, then your .htaccess should look like below.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.mywebsite.com/error
```

(or)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.mywebsite.com/error.php(error.html)
```

Otherwise if you are showing the file extension in the url, then it should be something like below

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.mywebsite.com/error.File Extension 
Example php error file: ErrorDocument 404 http://www.mywebsite.com/error.php
```

Let me know if issue is fixed and accept my answer.